# unable to build an executable out of CUDA Samples using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I am trying to make executables out of the Cuda Samples . My specs are CUDA 11.5 with Visual Studio 2019. When I check on the samples.sln file to build the executable of all the CUDA samples, I get the following message:

> "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
> Samples\v11.5\7_CUDALibraries\batchedLabelMarkersAndLabelCompressionNPP\batchedLabelMarkersAndLabelCompressionNPP_vs2019.vcxproj
> : error : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
> 11.5.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
> 11.5.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
> Samples\v11.5\7_CUDALibraries\batchedLabelMarkersAndLabelCompressionNPP\batchedLabelMarkersAndLabelCompressionNPP_vs2019.vcxproj"

Some background:
I understand that it is important to check compatibility of your CUDA version with Virtual Studio. To that end, when I had initially installed VS 2022 Community edition and then I attempted to install CUDA 11.5, I got the message that CUDA couldn't locate VS on my system. Then I tried installing VS 2019 first and then I tried to re-install CUDA 11.5. This time, I did not get the previous warning message and thought that all was good. But alas that was not the case!:(

Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated on how to tackle this issue! Thank you in advance

Answer (score -2):

Solved:
The following configuration ran fine:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, Nsight
Visual Studio Edition 4.7, and CUDA 7.5.